# How can I query a string in a non case sensitive way?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

My question is as simple as that : I have a query and I am looking for a match on a string such as :

```
const test_name = 'ExAmPlE'
const database_resources = await prisma.market.findMany({
    where: {
        name: test_name
    }
})
```

I can use `string.toLowerCase()` but only on specific use cases

How can I get all of the rows where name can be anything such as `Example`, `ExAMple` or `example` but not any other key such as `Exàmplé` ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depends on your DB. Quoting from the docs:

**PostgreSQL** uses deterministic collation by default, which means that filtering is **case-sensitive**. To support case-insensitive filtering, use the `mode: 'insensitive'` property on a per-field basis:

```js
const test_name = 'ExAmPlE'
const database_resources = await prisma.market.findMany({
    where: {
        name: {
            equals: test_name,
            mode: 'insensitive'
        }
    }
})
```

**MySQL** uses **case-insensitive** collation by default. Therefore, filtering with Prisma Client and MySQL is case-insensitive by default. `mode: 'insensitive'` property is not required and therefore not available in the generated Prisma Client API.

[See docs for more info about other providers](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/case-sensitivity#options-for-case-insensitive-filtering)

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the following:

```
prisma.market.findMany({
  where: {
    name: {
      contains: filter
    }
  }
})
```

And if you want to filter using more than one property, you can try out the following

```
prisma.market.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      {
        name: {
          contains: filter
        }
      },
      {
        description: {
          contains: filter
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: I see how it could help in some circumstances but how can it help for case sensitivity ?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add a couple use cases for people who land here looking for another use-cases i found useful.

If you want to find a record with field that contains some word (case-insensitive):

```
const search = 'ExAmPlE';
const results = await prisma.market.findMany({
    where: {
        name: {
            contains: search,
            mode: 'insensitive',
        },
    },
});
```

If you want to find a record with field that somewhat contains a word (case-insensitive):

```
const search = 'ExAmPlE';
const searchLike = `%${search}%`;
const results = await prisma.market.findMany({
    where: {
        name: {
            contains: searchLike,
            mode: 'insensitive',
        },
    },
});
```

If you want to find a record with some fields that are containing a word (case-insensitive):

```
const search = 'ExAmPlE';
const results = await prisma.market.findMany({
    where: {
        OR: [
            {
                name: {
                    contains: search,
                    mode: 'insensitive',
                },
            },
            {
                otherField: {
                    contains: search,
                    mode: 'insensitive',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
});
```